# Load xml using variable in actionscript 3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I want to load xml based on what button is pushed by changing the name of a variable.

For instance, there will be a string:

```
var whatscreens:String = "screens";
```

On clicking a button, I will change the string to whatever, and then I want to use that string to load the xml like:

```
loadXML(MovieClip(parent.parent).feedXML.feed.whatscreens);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. How do I put a working variable into this line?
I tried :

```
loadXML(MovieClip(parent.parent).feedXML.feed. + whatscreens );
```

but that gave me errors as well.

Lil help?

Comment: Is `feedml` and XML object? Are you perform EX4 traversing? More details please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `screens` is a property of `feed`, you'll do:

```
loadXML(MovieClip(parent.parent).feedXML.feed[whatscreens]);
```